# Keep remaining numbers in range 100 except numbers in the array

Tags: python, arrays

Array

```
a = (0, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 26, 26, 28, 33, 38, 41, 42, 42, 51, 52, 61, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 73, 76, 79, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 93, 94, 96, 97)
```

How to print the remaining numbers in the range 0-100, except those numbers in `a`?

Comment: Minor terminology nitpick: this is a tuple, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and subtract `a` from the range of numbers 0 - 100:

```
a = (0, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 26, 26, 28, 33, 38, 41, 42, 42, 51, 52, 61, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 73, 76, 79, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 93, 94, 96, 97)

print(set(range(101)) - set(a))
```

Prints:

```
{1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 63, 66, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 77, 78, 80, 81, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 95, 98, 99, 100}
```

If order is crucial, you can filter the range by removing items in a -- still using `set(a)` to make it efficient.

```
a = (0, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 26, 26, 28, 33, 38, 41, 42, 42, 51, 52, 61, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 73, 76, 79, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 93, 94, 96, 97)
s_a = set(a)

filtered = [n for n in range(101) if n not in s_a]
```

Comment: `set` is unordered.  It's an implementation detail that the numbers are displayed in order in this case.

Comment: You are correct @MarkTolonen. The question didn't say anything about the order and I overlooked it, so just in case, I've added an ordered alternative.

Comment: Could do `sorted(set(...))` as well.

Comment: Indeed, but the sort adds to the complexity, where the filtered list comprehension should be linear.

Comment: Sometimes the complex solution is faster due to C implementation, but I timed it and it wasn't in this case.  Save 4us using the filter.  Always time if you care :)